# How do I retrieve Logic App Workflow Settings with PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I'm trying to retrieve LogicApp Workflow Settings with PowerShell. Specifically it's about the Access Control configuration (and API Connections). It does not seem possible to retrieve the Access Control with the [Get-AzLogicApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/get-azlogicapp?view=azps-5.8.0). How do I retrieve this?

[image: Screenshot: LogicApp -> Workflow Settings -> Access Control Configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently logic app doesn't support this feature to get the workflow setting information

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After some research, we seem to be unable to obtain the IP address range there. The document does not give the methods that can be used, and there are no related properties after calling `Get-AzLogicApp`.

[image]

This is [all the parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.logic.models.workflow?view=azure-dotnet#properties) of the output of `Get-AzLogicApp`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get-AzLogicApp doesn't appear to contain it, but you can use Get-AzResource:

```
$resourcegroupName = "***"
$logicAppName = "***"
$logicApp = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/workflows -Name $logicAppName
$logicApp.properties.accessControl
```

E.g.,

```
$logicApp.properties.accessControl.triggers.allowedCallerIpAddresses.addressRange
$logicApp.properties.accessControl.actions.allowedCallerIpAddresses.addressRange
$logicApp.properties.accessControl.contents.allowedCallerIpAddresses.addressRange
```